# How to iterate over grouped results in ThinkingSphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I'm having trouble figuring out how to loop over the results of a ThinkingSphinx search that has been set to `group_by`. I currently have the following:

```
search = Event.search(
  {
    group_by: 'category_id', 
    group_function: :attr
  }
)
search.each_with_groupby_and_count do |event, group, count|
  puts [event, group, count].join(' - ')
end
```

This, however, only returns one record per category. It seems like the group and count values are correct, but I only get the first Event of each category, which I would have expected to be all the events in the group. Is it possible to get an array of Hashes or similar? Furthermore, if this is possible, would the `per_page` option be per group?

I would expect each_with_group_and_count to iterate over something like this:

```
[
   {group: 1, hits: [Event1, Event2], count: 2},
   {group: 2: hits: [Event3], count: 1}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid Sphinx's grouping functionality doesn't behave in that matter - it only returns one document (in this situation, one event) per group value.

It may be more appropriate to just sort by category_id instead, and track when it changes as you iterate over it (or use `Enumerable#group_by` to group all events by category_id) - keep in mind that Sphinx paginates results, so you may want to increase the default page size (with `:per_page`) depending on how you're using these results.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Sorting by category and tracking the change doesn't solve my issue, since I want to display the first 10 results per category. If the first category happens to have 100 events, and the results per page are 100, I would have to iterate through multiple pages in order to get the results I need, which would be somewhat unpredictable. I think in this case it's best to just make separate queries for each category. Thanks for your insight.